# Select Query does not find existing record

Tags: c#, datetime

The [Date] field in data base is `DateTime`  and it puts data in this format [image].  The problem is in debugging mode. When I send date ([image]) to the query. The query does not find any record. I think it is because of the difference in hours. So I tried `DateTime.Now.Date`, but it is still not working(The hours part still exist)

```
SELECT [Employee_Id]  
FROM [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[Date] 
where [Date]=@dateTime;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the query to search against the `datetime`'s date and send a date only;

```
...
where cast([date] as date) = @date
```

(This way remains sargable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this or CAST like Alex K suggests:

```
WHERE DATEPART(year,[DATE]) = DATEPART(year,@dateTime) 
  AND DATEPART(dy,[DATE]) = DATEPART(dy,@dateTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [Date] is a datetime, it is trying to compare the entire value (not just the date).

If you're trying to filter by date, and not datetime, then change your where to something like this:

```
where DATEPART(YEAR, [Date])=DATEPART(YEAR, @dateTime) 
AND DATEPART(MONTH, [Date])=DATEPART(MONTH, @dateTime) 
AND DATEPART(DAY, [Date])=DATEPART(DAY, @dateTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also pass interval of datetimes and check if your column is within it.

```
where [Date]>=@lowerBound and [Date]<@upperBound;
```

For todays records lower bound of interval would be `DateTime.Now.Date`, upper bound `DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1)`. This way you'll keep benefits from indexed `[Date]` if it is indexed.